# Can we use while loop in Excel sheet for getting the smallest no

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2007, excel-formula

I am using MS-Excel for storing more than 2000 records.
I need a formula that will take a from one cell say cell `E3` and match it with all cells in that row.
If it finds the match then it should display the value at that column's header.
lets say `E3` matches with `C3` then it should display the value which is at the `C1` cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you seek is

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(E3,3:3,0))
```